# Behaviour of DateEntry in Tkinter Window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkcalendar

I have a button that adds a DateEntry widget to a scrollable frame. Unfortunately, the frame is at the bottom of the window, so after adding a few rows, the dropdown calendar hides behind the task bar. Is there any way to change it, so the calendar opens above the field, rather than below?[image]

Here is some test code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry

master = Tk()

global rowNumForShiftReport
rowNumForShiftReport=0
shiftDateWidgetList=[]

def myfunction(event):
    canvas2.configure(scrollregion=canvas2.bbox("all"), width=100, height=100)

def addEntry2():
    global rowNumForShiftReport


    rowNumForShiftReport = rowNumForShiftReport + 1
    shiftDateWidgetList.append(DateEntry(frame2, state='readonly', width=15))
    shiftDateWidgetList[-1].grid(row=rowNumForShiftReport, column=0)
    rowNumForShiftReport+1


master.geometry('400x400')
btn_addField2 = ttk.Button(master, text="Add Entry",command=addEntry2)
btn_addField2.grid(row=0, column=1)
#lotFrame2 = Frame(master)
actualLabelFrame=ttk.LabelFrame(master, text="Shift Report", height=300, width=300)
actualLabelFrame.grid(row=0, column=0)
canvas2 = Canvas(actualLabelFrame,width=160)
frame2 = Frame(canvas2,width=160)
frame2.bind("<Configure>", myfunction)
canvas2.create_window((0, 0), window=frame2, anchor='nw')
scrollBar2 = ttk.Scrollbar(actualLabelFrame, orient="vertical", command=canvas2.yview)
canvas2.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollBar2.set)
scrollBar2.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=N + S)
canvas2.grid(row=0, column=1)



mainloop()
```

Comment: I think you need to patch `DateEntry` to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the goal by extending `DateEntry` and override its `drop_down()` function as below:

```py
class MyDateEntry(DateEntry):
    def drop_down(self):
        """Display or withdraw the drop-down calendar depending on its current state."""
        if self._calendar.winfo_ismapped():
            self._top_cal.withdraw()
        else:
            self._validate_date()
            date = self.parse_date(self.get())
            x = self.winfo_rootx()
            y = self.winfo_rooty() + self.winfo_height()
            if self.winfo_toplevel().attributes('-topmost'):
                self._top_cal.attributes('-topmost', True)
            else:
                self._top_cal.attributes('-topmost', False)
            # - patch begin: make sure the drop-down calendar is visible
            if x+self._top_cal.winfo_width() > self.winfo_screenwidth():
                x = self.winfo_screenwidth() - self._top_cal.winfo_width()
            if y+self._top_cal.winfo_height() > self.winfo_screenheight()-30:
                y = self.winfo_rooty() - self._top_cal.winfo_height()
            # - patch end
            self._top_cal.geometry('+%i+%i' % (x, y))
            self._top_cal.deiconify()
            self._calendar.focus_set()
            self._calendar.selection_set(date)
```

Then replace all `DateEntry(...)` by `MyDateEntry(...)` in your code.

*Note that it is based on `tkcalendar` v1.6.1.*

Comment: Is there some documentation or tutorials on positioning of the windows? I always found it hard to understand the correct positioning while making custom widget classes.